# Android Canvas Redo and Undo Operation

Tags: android

I am working on a drawing project.  My code is working perfectly other than canvas redo and undo operations.  My undo operation removes paths from the `paths` ArrayList and saves to the `undonePaths` ArrayList, and the redo operation removes the last element from `undonePaths` and saves to `paths`.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint       mPaint;   
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 

    private Bitmap im;
    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);

        im=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    }               
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //mPath = new Path();
            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            for (Path p : paths){
                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            }
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw            
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        public void onClickUndo () { 
            if (paths.size()>0) 
            { 
               undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
               invalidate();
             }
            else
            {

            }
             //toast the user 
        }

        public void onClickRedo (){
           if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
           { 
               paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
               invalidate();
           } 
           else 
           {

           }
             //toast the user 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  touch_start(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  touch_move(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  touch_up();
                  invalidate();
                  break;
          }
          return true;
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly for drawing but not working perfectly for undo and redo operations.  What's wrong with my code?

Here's my full source code:

http://www.4shared.com/rar/8PQQEZdH/test_draw.html

### **UPDATED:**

**Finally my problem was solved; here's my drawing class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint       mPaint;   
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 

    private Bitmap im;
    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();

        im=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    }               
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //mPath = new Path();
            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            for (Path p : paths){
                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            }
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            undonePaths.clear();
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            paths.add(mPath);
            mPath = new Path();            

        }

        public void onClickUndo () { 
            if (paths.size()>0) 
            { 
               undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
               invalidate();
             }
            else
            {

            }
             //toast the user 
        }

        public void onClickRedo (){
           if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
           { 
               paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
               invalidate();
           } 
           else 
           {

           }
             //toast the user 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  touch_start(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  touch_move(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  touch_up();
                  invalidate();
                  break;
          }
          return true;
    }
}
```

**That code is working perfectly...!**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first glance I see the following problems:

- By adding your empty `Path` to `paths` as soon as you make it, you're going to have a problem as soon as you undo: you're popping that empty `Path` first, making the first undo not seem to work.  Then if you draw into that `Path`, it's not added to `paths`.  The solution is to add the completed `Path` to paths in `touch_up()` before creating a new one.

That is, remove

```
paths.add(mPath);
```

from the constructor, and in `touch_up()`, change

```
mPath = new Path();
paths.add(mPath);
```

to

```
paths.add(mPath);
mPath = new Path();
```

You'll also want to add

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

after your `for` loop in `onDraw()` in order to draw the in-progress `Path`.

- You're not emptying `undonePaths` when the user starts drawing again.

Answer (score 6):

Please check below code it is working..

```
package com.testpath;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TesUndoPaintActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout linearLayout2;
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        final DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel(this);
        linearLayout2.addView(dp);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (paths.size() > 0) {
                            undonePaths.add(paths
                                    .remove(paths.size() - 1));
                            dp.invalidate();
                        }
                    }
                });
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2))
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (undonePaths.size()>0) { 
                       paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1));
                       dp.invalidate();
                   } 
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mPaint, circlePaint, outercirclePaint;

        // private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private float xleft, xright, xtop, xbottom;

        public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            this.setOnTouchListener(this);

            circlePaint = new Paint();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            outercirclePaint = new Paint();
            outercirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            outercirclePaint.setColor(0x44FFFFFF);
            circlePaint.setColor(0xAADD5522);
            outercirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            outercirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            for (Path p : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            }

        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // if (x <= cx+circleRadius+5 && x>= cx-circleRadius-5) {
                // if (y<= cy+circleRadius+5 && cy>= cy-circleRadius-5){
                // paths.clear();
                // return true;
                // }
                // }
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And Below XML File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Undo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Redo" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please check it.

Comment: your code is working perfectly,but, one problem undo button first time click not undo drawing how to solve this?

Comment: +1, Thanks for your effect hats off!.sorry, your code always working but some problem,i found answer from @Darshan Computing

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

The path is only shown when you finish drawing it which leaves the user clueless as to what he is drawing

### Solution

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

   for (Path p : paths){
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }

    //Draw path along with the finger
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

Add **`canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint)`** to **`onDraw()`** so the user gets a feeling of actually painting on the canvas.

Comment: This is posted as an answer, but it doesn't address any part of the question.  (And the accepted answer already addresses this problem.)