# Change color in drawing view android

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, android-view

I have created a view that user can draw in it, but the problem is when user is drawing and wants to change the color. He clicks, chooses the new color and when he starts drawing all the previous that was drawn on the view changes color to the new one. I need the new color to be applied only to the new lines not the previous ones that have been drawn.

Here is my view code:

```
public class SignatureView extends View {

    private float STROKE_WIDTH = 5;

    /** Need to track this so the dirty region can accommodate the stroke. **/
    private final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    /**
     * Optimizes painting by invalidating the smallest possible area.
     */
    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public float getBrushSize() {
        return STROKE_WIDTH;
    }

    public void setBrushSize(float brushSize) {
        this.STROKE_WIDTH = brushSize;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * Erases the signature.
     */
    public void clear() {
        path.reset();

        // Repaints the entire view.
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Start tracking the dirty region.
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

            // When the hardware tracks events faster than they are delivered,
            // the
            // event will contain a history of those skipped points.
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }

            // After replaying history, connect the line to the touch point.
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        default:
            // Log.("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        // Include half the stroke width to avoid clipping.
        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
     * points.
     */
    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the dirty region when the motion event occurs.
     */
    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

        // The lastTouchX and lastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN
        // motion event occurred.
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

}
```

User is changing the color using this function on click from an activity

```
public void colorpicker() {
        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this,
                signature.getColor(), new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

                        signature.setColor(color);
                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

How can I apply the code to the newly drawn lines in my view without affecting the old ones?

Comment: @AshaSoman code updated

Answer (score 0):

That's perhaps your entire view is redrawn when you change color.
So keep record of all your paths and reset it in your `onDraw()` method as show in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002261/android-drawing-apps-line-once-change-colour-all-the-previously-lines-drawn-are).