# Undo function in painting removing all paths

Tags: android, android-canvas

Suppose I have drawn two lines and The second line which i have just drawn , I want to remove it. SO I have written the following piece of code for removing the last drawn line. The Code is as under

```
 public void onClickUndoLast() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {

                undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
                invalidate();

        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }
```

It is removing the path but it is clearing all the canvas with the paths. I do not know what is the problem. ?  I am using the same class as used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409072/undo-and-redo-in-canvas-for-android) question. SO please do not mark this question as a duplicate as The solution given there is not working . DO you guys have any idea. ?

**Edit 1:**

My on Draw method is like this

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    /*
     * Draw the image into center
     */
    //int cx = (mWidth - mBitmap.getWidth()) >> 1; // same as (...) / 2
    //int cy = (mHeight - mBitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    for (PathPoints p : paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getStrockWidth());
        if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
            //canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
        }
    }
    //mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
    mPaint.setColor(myPaintColor);
    //for overlapping
   // mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(myPaintColor, 90, AvoidXfermode.Mode.AVOID));
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could post the exact code you have. But from what you say, to achieve what you are looking for you need to have your `onDraw()` method like below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // some code
        for (Path p : paths){
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        // some code
    }
```

`paths` is the `List` of `Path` object. So each time you draw a new path, just add it to this list. Once you press the *undo* button, remove the last item from the list and call `invalidate()`. This way, each time you press *undo*, the number of paths drawn is decreased by 1.

Comment: I know this logic , I am sharing my on draw method, due to some reasons I have slightly updated it,

Comment: It should work. You say that the whole canvas is cleared when you click on `undo`. Just add a `Log` in `onDraw()`, to see if stuff inside `for` is getting executed after `undo`.

Comment: what do you think ?  on clear the on draw shold run again